# How use google drive api in a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, api, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I am creating a chrome extension and I would like to use the google drive api in it.

Except I can't call a remote script in my code because of the content_security_policy.

Here is my hello.html :

[image: 1]

and my manifest.json :

[image: 2]

Here is the error :
Error
'content_security_policy.extension_pages': CSP directive 'object-src' must be specified (either explicitly, or implicitly via 'default-src') and must allowlist only secure resources.
Could not load manifest.

I tried a lot of different content_security_policies but nothing works.
Is this the best way to access google drive api or should I do something else?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: This API can't be used in an extension page. You can use `fetch` directly, not via the gapi object, but that would require you to make the requests explicitly/manually. The only way to use gapi object in ManifestV3 is to do it inside a [sandboxed frame](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox) inside your popup or `chrome.offscreen` document.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok thanks, I'll look into doing it with fetch then